# Replace characters with substring using a loop Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, replace, replaceall

I am trying to replace each instance of what is between two brackets using a loop and an array. array1a and array1b are the indices of where the brackets open and close. I want to get the number between the two brackets and increment it by one and replace the value currently there, but as the string text is currently a list (such as "list item (0) list item (10) list item (1023)" I want to use a loop to increment the value of each rather than to set all the values within brackets to the same value. I hope this makes sense!

```
String text = myString.getText();

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                array2[x] = text.substring(array1a[x], array1b[x]);
                array2[x] = array2[x] + 1;
                array3[x] = "(" + array2[x] + ")";
                String text2 = text.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", array3[x]);
                myString.setText(text2);
            }
```

Full Code:

```
public class CreateVideoList extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton play = new JButton("Play Playlist");
    JButton addVideo = new JButton("Add Video");
    TextArea playlist = new TextArea(6, 50);
    JTextField videoNo = new JTextField(2);
    private int x = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String key = videoNo.getText();
        String name = VideoData.getName(key);
        String director = VideoData.getDirector(key);
        Integer playCount = VideoData.getPlayCount(key);
        String text = playlist.getText();
        String rating = CheckVideos.stars(VideoData.getRating(key));
        String output = name + " - " + director + "\nRating: "
                + rating
                + "\nPlay Count: " + playCount;
        String newItem = key + " " + name + " - " + director + " ("
                + playCount + ") " + "\n";
        String addToList = "";
        String[] array3 = new String[100];

        if ("Add Video".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0)) == false) {
                playlist.setText("");
            }
            if (addToList.indexOf(key) == -1) {
                addToList += addToList + newItem;
                playlist.append(addToList);
                array3[x] = key;
                x++;
            } else if (addToList.indexOf(key) != -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CreateVideoList.this,
                        "This video is already in the playlist. Please select a"
                        + " different video.", "Add to playlist error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        if ("Play Playlist".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            Integer length = (text.length());
            int counta = 0;
            Integer[] array1a = new Integer[100];
            Integer[] array1b = new Integer[100];
            String strPlayCount = "";

            for (x = 0; x < length; x++) {
                if (text.charAt(x) == '(') {
                    counta++;
                    array1a[counta - 1] = x;
                    array1a[counta - 1] = array1a[counta - 1] + 1;
                }
                if (text.charAt(x) == ')') {
                    array1b[counta - 1] = x;
                    array1b[counta - 1] = array1b[counta - 1];
                }
            }
            String[] array2 = new String[counta];
            String[] array4 = new String[100];

            for (int y = 0; y < counta; y++) {
                array2[y] = text.substring(array1a[y], array1b[y]);
                array2[y] = array2[y] + 1;
                playCount = Integer.parseInt(array2[y]);
                array4[y] = "(" + array2[y] + ")";
                String text2 = text.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", array4[y]);
                playlist.setText(text2);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete code example that we can compile and get the same result you do. You are missing a class, a method, and several variable declarations.

Comment: Just curious, what are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: What is the purpose of representing numbers as strings? You need to reconsider your data structure.

Comment: I am trying to make a playlist and when the 'play' button is pressed i want each song's play count to increment by one

Comment: The string representation is a *rending* of the song's state. Don't store state in a string. Create a Song class with a `int plays` field and a `toString()` method that returns the song title with the number of plays in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
array2[x] = array2[x] + 1;
array3[x] = "(" + array2[x] + ")";
```

with

```
Integer n = Integer.parseInt(array2[x]) + 1;
array3[x] = "(" + n.toString() + ")";
```

Comment: what I was looking for was more how can I replace each instance between the brackets individually, but thanks anyway